# value-of does not return any value

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have a XSL that i'm creating, which looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <datum><xsl:value-of select="/wechselkurse/datum[1]" /></datum>
    <kurs><xsl:value-of select="/wechselkurse/devise[@code='eur']/kurs" /></kurs>
</xsl:template>
```

the input looks like this:

```
<wechselkurse xmlns="http://www.afd.admin.ch/publicdb/newdb/mwst_kurse" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.afd.admin.ch/publicdb/newdb/mwst_kurse http://www.afd.admin.ch/publicdb/newdb/mwst_kurse/tageskurse.xsd">
<datum>2011-10-25</datum>
<zeit>04:30:39</zeit>
<devise code="egp">
    <land_de>Ägypten</land_de>
    <land_fr>Egypte</land_fr>
    <land_it>Egitto</land_it>
    <land_en>Egypt</land_en>
    <waehrung>100 EGP</waehrung>
    <kurs>14.90711</kurs>
</devise>
<devise code="all">
    <land_de>Albanien</land_de>
    <land_fr>Albanie</land_fr>
    <land_it>Albania</land_it>
    <land_en>Albania</land_en>
    <waehrung>100 ALL</waehrung>
    <kurs>0.88044</kurs>
</devise>
```

and so on. The only output i'm getting looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datum/>
<kurs/>
```

so I'm essentially just not getting any value from the source xml. the Element Devise exists with the attribute code=eur i'm sure of that, but I just can't figure out why I'm not receiving anything from the source XML.

PLease help me.

Comment: It's an XML namespace issue. Sorry, no time for a full anser. Let me suggest you this: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namensraum_%28XML%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are about one million things wrong with your .xsl but the most important is that you are  not using namespaces.

Your .xml contains this namespace : `xmlns="http://www.afd.admin.ch/publicdb/newdb/mwst_kurse"`

However you don't use it in your .xsl file. To do this first declare it and then use it to access the elements you want :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xml:space="preserve"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:n="http://www.afd.admin.ch/publicdb/newdb/mwst_kurse">

    <xsl:output method='xml'/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <datum><xsl:value-of select="n:wechselkurse/n:datum" />

        </datum>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In addition , a .xml file can only have a **single** root element. So you have to change your .xsl file.